# Laravel error: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT()

Tags: laravel

Anyone familiar with  this Laravel Error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select office, avg(q1) as q1, avg(q2) as q2 from `feedback`)"

This is my controller code:

```
$feedback_data = DB::table('feedback')
    ->select(DB::raw('office, avg(q1) as q1, avg(q2) as q2'))
    ->get();
return view('/feedback/index')->with('feedback_data', $feedback_data);
```

Comment: Do you want to get the average values per `office`?

Comment: the average value of q1, q2, q3, q4

Comment: The average values of *all* rows? Or per `office`?

Comment: i want it per office

Comment: You need to add a `GROUP BY office` clause to your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `groupBy()`:

```php
$feedback_data = DB::table('feedback')
    ->select(DB::raw('office, avg(q1) as q1, avg(q2) as q2'))
    ->groupBy('office')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This answer my problem. Thank You!!

Answer (score 9):

While using `MIN(),MAX(),COUNT() AVG()` like agregate functions you have to use `GROUP BY` , But As per latest `MYSQL` version You have to use all the columns in select query as a `GROUP BY`.

**So for solving this error there are 2 ways:**

1. **You can use `GROUP BY` on relevant column.**
2. **You can disable the strict mode in `config/database.php` by setting it to `false`.**

`GROUP BY` is already showed in one of the answer given here so we will talk about strict mode, so laravel has strict mode as `true` by default which does not allow to group by on single column so you have to set the strict mode to `false` if you want group by on single column.

Disabling "strict" mode, returns to the <= `MYSQL 5.6` behavior while enabling "strict" mode, set it to the `MYSQL 5.7` behavior and we want to disable it because disabling it will allow us to group by on single column.

So for setting strict mode go to `config/database.php` and set strict mode to `false`.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false, //it will be true by default set this to false
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```